I'm encountering an issue sending notifications to specific users using Angular and SignalR
Notifications to all users work successfully.
When I use Clients.All:
when i use Clients.All
However, when I try to send notifications to specific users, I see a success message, but the notifications are not received.
This my .NET code:
public async Task<IActionResult> SendNotificationToUser(string userName, string message)
{
     using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
     {
         var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
         var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

         if (user != null)
         {
             await _hubContext.Clients.User(user.Id).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
             return Ok(new { Message = "Notification sent to user" });
         }

         return NotFound(new { Message = "User not found" });
     }
}

My Angular code:
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: HubConnection | undefined;
  private messageSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {}

  startConnection(): void {
    if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';
      const options: IHttpConnectionOptions = {
        accessTokenFactory: () => token
      };

      this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://localhost:7163/Notify', options)
        .build();

      this.hubConnection.start()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Connexion établie avec succès');
          this.hubConnection?.on('ReceiveMessage', (message: string) => {
            console.log(message);
            this.messageSubject.next(message);
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error('Erreur lors du démarrage de la connexion : ', err);
        });

      this.hubConnection.onclose((error) => {
        console.log('Connexion fermée : ', error);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.startConnection();
        }, 5000);
      });
    } else {
      console.error('localStorage is not available in this environment.');
    }
  }

  getMessageSubject(): Subject<string> {
    return this.messageSubject;
  }


  sendNotificationToUser(user: string, message: string): void {
    if (this.hubConnection) {
      this.hubConnection.invoke('SendNotificationToUser', user, message)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    } else {
      console.error('Hub connection is not initialized.');
    }
  }
}

I'm waiting for your favorable response.

In your C# code, what is the userName? Is it an email?

Yes exactly in C# code userName typically refers to the user's email.

Then, can you try await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userName)?

I tried it before, but it's still not working

Please see this link for how SignalR manages Identity Users: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-8.0#users-in-signalr. By default, user.NameIdentifier is used to identify a specific user.

Any news guys ? still same issue

Hi Rachad, please set breakpoint here this.hubConnection?.on('ReceiveMessage', (message: string) => {             console.log(message);             this.messageSubject.next(message);           });, check front-end can receive message or not.

I guess the issue is related to Json serialize issue, you can try to enable server side logging.

Not received in front

however when i try to use users.All() for sending to all users everything looks good

Hi Rachad, try to enable server side logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-8.0#server-side-logging.
